# Decoupling AngularJS scope variable values from local variable values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
$scope.encryptSend = function(payload, tempPwd){
var local = payload;
local.password = Encryption.encrypt(tempPwd);
local.confirm_password = local.password;
$http.post('REST API URL', local).success(function(response) {
  CommonService.setLogin(true);
  $state.go('home.bookings');
});
}


$scope.doRegister = function() {
var tempPwd = $scope.signUpData.password;
var tempCPwd = $scope.signUpData.confirm_password;
var data = $scope.signUpData;

if ($scope.signUpData.tc) {
  if ($scope.signUpData.password === $scope.signUpData.confirm_password) {
    var payload = data;
    $scope.encryptSend(payload, tempPwd);
  }
}
};
```

Below is the HTML code:

```
<ion-view title="Signup" id="page6" class=" ">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form id="signup-form3" class="list ">
      <ion-list id="signup-list3" class=" ">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="signup-input3">
          <span class="input-label">Business Name</span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Business Name" ng-model="signUpData.business_name">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="signup-input4">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="signUpData.username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="signup-input5">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="signUpData.password">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="signup-input6">
          <span class="input-label">Confirm Password</span>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="signUpData.confirm_password">
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="signup-input6">
          <span class="input-label">Email Id</span>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email Id" ng-model="signUpData.emailId">
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="signup-input6">
          <span class="input-label">Mobile Number</span>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" ng-model="signUpData.mobileNo">
        </label>
        <ion-checkbox ng-model="signUpData.tc">I agree to the Terms & Conditions</ion-checkbox>

      </ion-list>
      <button id="signup-button3" class=" button button-positive  button-block " ng-click="doRegister()">Sign up
      </button>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I am trying to encrypt the password and send it to the rest api. But the password textfield in the form, when I click submit displays the encrypted password.

I have copied the entire data into a series of local variables. But still somehow the $scope.signupdata is reflecting the encrypted text. And I am not able to decouple the encrypted text from the $scope.signupdata.

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is payload and local is the same object, thus changing local.password changes `$scope.signUpData.password` eventually. So, try copying the payload.

```
$scope.encryptSend = function(payload, tempPwd){
var local = angular.copy(payload);
local.password = Encryption.encrypt(tempPwd);
local.confirm_password = local.password;
$http.post('REST API URL', local).success(function(response) {
  CommonService.setLogin(true);
  $state.go('home.bookings');
});
}
```

`angular.copy` creates a deep copy of source `payload`. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I had forgotten about objects being copied by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I believe the problem is that objects are passed by reference, so var local = payload, sets local to the same object as $scope.signUpData, rather than a copy of it.

Strings on the other hand, are passed by value. If you try setting up local as a blank object (var local = {}) and copying strings to it's properties, it should no longer update $scope.signUpData.password because the reference will be broken.